# Make Javascript local variable to global for recursive loops

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion, scope

I have a recursive function which has a local variable.
It calls itself on specific condition.
The local variable needs to be updated, but every call it creates a new local variable specific to the current function scope.
How can i reach the local variable for access all recursive loop and not to create a new one?
Something like __Callee.varname?

The code is:

```
var addAttribute = function(object,elem)
{
    var attributes = [];

    // only attribute without values
    if ( object instanceof Array )
    {
        for ( var value in object )
        {
            attributes.push(object[value]);
        }
    }
    // attribute with values
    else if ( object instanceof Object )
    {
        for ( var key in object )
        {
            if ( object[key] instanceof Array )
            {
                addAttribute(object[key],elem);
            }
            else
            {
                attributes.push(key+'=\''+object[key]+'\'');
            }
        }
    }
    // Only one attribute
    else if ( typeof object === 'string' )
    {
        attributes.push('\''+object+'\'');
    }
    // Invalid parameter
    else
    {
        console.log('Invalid parameter: '+typeof object);
    }

    console.log('<'+elem+' '+attributes.join(' ').toString()+' />');

}
```

I do not want to make variable to global because of using this name in other functions and global scope already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a closure

```
function fn() {
    function recursiveFunction() {
        // do something with x
        recursiveFunction();
    }
    var x = 0;
    recursiveFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing is to pass it into the function, possibly optionally:

```
var addAttribute = function(object,elem, attributes) {
    attributes = attributes || [];
    // ....
```

Then when calling it recursively, pass in the third argument:

```
addAttribute(object[key], value, attributes);
```

Here's a much simplified example demonstrating:

```js
function foo(num, array) {
  array = array || [];
  array.push(num);
  console.log("Pushed " + num + ", array = " + JSON.stringify(array));
  if (num < 5) {
    foo(num + 1, array);
  }
}
foo(1);
```

Comment: It wont work because the caller function attribute can not be set to the called function attribute.

Comment: @NémethPéter: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the caller function attribute" or "the called function attribute". The above would use a single shared array, exactly like the single shared `x` in Nina's answer.